# Google cloud user accounts & linux groups don't get added to new bitnami lamp instances?

Tags: google-compute-engine

So I've went into `permissions -> user accounts` and added a linux group then added a couple of accounts and gave each of them an SSH key. I've then created a Bitnami LAMP instance, shouldn't that new instance have that group and those users and the users should be able to access them with their SSH keys?

Its description reads:

> Create Linux user accounts to give yourself and others access to your
>   VM instances. A user account lets you log in to all Linux instances in
>   your project and has its own username and home directory on each
>   instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your Bitnami LAMP instance to recognize user accounts you need to enable it through startup script, as mentioned on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/#setup):

> User accounts are recognized only on instances that have been enabled to use user accounts. To create an instance that recognizes user accounts, run the following startup script when you start an instance. The startup script is located at:
>
> gs://gcua-beta/startup.sh

Moreover, user accounts feature is in beta and is supported for the following operating systems. As such, you need to make sure your operating system is supported.

- Backported Debian 7
- Debian 8
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Ubuntu 14.10
- Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I can't find the startup.sh file, is that on the instance?

Comment: Starting from step 3 I don't understand what they want me to do... :(

Comment: You can go to your Developer console click on your instance. On the instance page click Edit button on the top, scroll down until you see Custom Metadata. Add 'startup-script-url' in the key box and 'gs://gcua-beta/startup.sh' in value. Click Save at the bottom of the page and than restart your instance. Once done your groups will sync to your instance. For more information on startup scripts you can visit [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).